# Does Android Marshmellow hotspot block apps?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, wifi-hotspot

I am trying to trace a problem with Teamviewer and I think the issue somewhere revolves around my smartphone.

I use Teamviewer 11, on a Windows 10 Tablet, using a Samsung Note 4 Mobile Hotspot on Vodafone UK.

Until last week on my Note 4 was Android 5.0.1 - everything worked as I would expect; I would load up Teamviewer, log in with my password and would be able to access my remote computers. I was then prompted for the 6.0.1 update (build MMB29M.N910FXXU1DPE1) and now I can not get a connection to Teamviewer servers.

Now, Teamviewer reports that the issue is with F-Secure (my AV/anti-spam), however with alternative connections under the same F-Secure conditions it works fine. So....

What I have tried:

- Connecting using a mobile hotspot on a BlackBerry Z10 (with the same Sim Card) - Works
- Connecting using my home wifi - Works
- Connecting using my Note 4, with firewall or AV disabled - Doesn't work

I have checked that my Note 4 hotspot is set as a private connection, the same as my other connections and there are no obvious differences.

Am I missing something in Android Marshmellow or does it do something differently?

Comment: Just a blind suggestion: Make sure Location is switched ON (High Accuracy) and try the app again. (I'm saying this because ShareIt wasn't working for me in Marshmallow, it worked only when I switched ON the 'Location' setting. I've no idea how it's related with Hotspot, but it worked).